# Display all prime numbers up to user's input limit

Tags: java

So I've been asked to define an algorithm to display all prime numbers up to a limit set up by the user.  I chose to use a nested **while** loops but for some reason the program remains stuck after printing the first prime number...

I've did this exercise on the paper line by line and can't figure out where is the problem. I appreciate any suggestion.

This is my code:

```
System.out.println("Display all prime numbers from 3 up to...");
int limit = sc.nextInt();
int iterator = 3, iterator2 = 2;
boolean isPrime = true;

while (limit >= iterator) {
  while (iterator > iterator2) {
    if (iterator % iterator2 != 0) {
      iterator2++;
    } else {
      isPrime = false;
    }
  }
  iterator2 = 2;
  if (isPrime == true) {
    System.out.print(iterator + ", ");
    }
  iterator++;
}
```

Comment: unrelated: you never reset the flag `isPrime`

Comment: why should I reset it ? my problem is that it never goes from true to false, even when it meets the condition iterator % iterator2 == 0...

Comment: well, it's not the direct source of the never ending loop, but not reseting it won't help to get the right result

Answer (score 0):

See what happens when `iterator=4`and `iterator2=2`:

```
iterator % iterator2 == 4%2 == 0
```

The second loop never stop looping as iterator 2 is never incremented.
Simply move the line `iterator2++;`out of the if/else block.

Plus, once you have check all divisors for one value of iterator, you need to reset the `isPrime` flag.

If you don't, once you found a non-prime number, the flag will always be set to false and all following numbers will be marked as non-prime number.

```
while (limit >= iterator) {
    isPrime = true;
    while (iterator > iterator2) {
        if (iterator % iterator2 == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
        }
        iterator2++;
    }
    iterator2 = 2;
    if (isPrime == true) {
        System.out.print(iterator + ", ");
    }
    iterator++;
}
```